# Como llamar a un a función en jquery sin repetir el código

Tags: jquery

Tengo una función en [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), la cual la cargo en el `document. ready` y me esta trabajando sin problema. El detalle lo tengo cuando quiero llamar a esa función desde un evento `onclick`.

La forma que tengo para hacerlo, es llamando nuevamente al código, desde el evento onclick pero lo que estoy tratando de evitar es repetir el código. Si alguien me puede ayudar:

**`Código`**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      //Este es el código que necesito llamar
      $.post('index.php?c=unidades&f=getmpuse',{id:id},function(data){
        val = (data.valor == null)?60:data.valor;
        pal = get_palabraramd();
        get_palminparant(val, get_textrandomlimt,30,pal);
        $("#rango").val(val);
        $("#palabras").val(val);                
   },'json');   
});
```

Comment: `Utilizar funciones` es la solución para no repetir el código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

          //Este es el código que necesito llamar.
          function tuFuncion(){
              $.post('index.php?c=unidades&f=getmpuse',{id:id},function(data){
                    val = (data.valor == null)?60:data.valor;
                    pal = get_palabraramd();
                    get_palminparant(val, get_textrandomlimt,30,pal);
                    $("#rango").val(val);
                    $("#palabras").val(val);               
              },'json');   
           } 
           tuFuncion(); //para que se ejecute por primera vez
           $('#mibotonAccion').click(tuFuncion); //ejemplo de al hacer click llamar a tu funcion
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Para evitar repetir el Código , puedes usar funciones , y así cada vez que quieras realizar dicha operación solo llamas a la función. En el siguiente ejemplo la función a ejecutar es `mifuncion()` donde solo muestro un `alert` en el `ready` del documento y en el evento `click` de `botón` llamo a dicha función. sin tener que escribir en los dos lados dicha operación.

```js
$(function() {
 mifuncion();
});

function mifuncion(){
 alert("Bien");
}

function eventolick(){
 mifuncion();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="eventolick();">Ejecutar Función</button>
```